# How do i get this data in the proper format?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

ok so i have this query

```
    select ss.system_step_id, ss.step_number, cd.name, ssp.system_step_product_id, p.cost, ssp.class_id from system_step ss 
    join system as s on s.system_id=ss.system_id 
    join category_description as cd on cd.category_id=ss.sub_category_id 
    join system_step_product as ssp on ss.system_step_id=ssp.system_step_id 
    join product as p on p.product_id=ssp.product_id where s.system_id = 41 
    order by ss.step_number, ssp.class_id;

which yields this result

7   1   Screens         808 115.0000 1
7   1   Screens         809 381.9000 2
7   1   Screens         810 441.9000 3
8   2   Printers        811 112.3200 1
8   2   Printers        812 201.0400 2
8   2   Printers        813 202.8700 3
9   3   Cash Drawers    814 135.7000 1
9   3   Cash Drawers    815 86.5400  2
9   3   Cash Drawers    816 135.7000 3
```

Is there a way to turn this into a php array of three elements like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => "Screens"
            [standard_product] => Array ([id] => 808, [price] => '115.0000')
            [business_product] => Array ([id] => 809, [price] => '381.9000')
            [premium_product] => Array ([id] => 810, [price] => '441.9000') 
        )                      

    [1] => Array               
        (                      
          [name] => "Printers"
          [standard_product] => Array ([id] => 811, [price] => '112.3200')
          [business_product] => Array ([id] => 812, [price] => '201.0400')
          [premium_product] => Array ([id] => 813, [price] => '202.8700')
        )
    [2] => Array               
        (                      
          [name] => "Cash Drawers"
          [standard_product] => Array ([id] => 814, [price] => '135.7000')
          [business_product] => Array ([id] => 815, [price] => '86.5400')
          [premium_product] => Array ([id] => 816, [price] => '135.7000')
        )
)


$sql = "select ss.system_step_id, ss.step_number, cd.name, ssp.system_step_product_id, p.cost, ssp.class_id, pd.name as product_name, pd.description from system_step ss join system as s on s.system_id=ss.system_id join category_description as cd on cd.category_id=ss.sub_category_id join system_step_product as ssp on ss.system_step_id=ssp.system_step_id join product as p on p.product_id=ssp.product_id join product_description as pd on pd.product_id=p.product_id where s.system_id = {$system['system_id']} order by ss.step_number, ssp.class_id;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$steps = array();
while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $steps[] = $row_r;
}
```

so steps is the the full array with 9 elements

As you can see the only thing of note is the class_id 1 is standard_product class_id 2 is business_product and class_id 3 is premium_product

Comment: it can be done with a foreach() loop

Comment: I assume you're getting query results via something like `mysql_fetch_assoc()` ?  It'll be easier to offer a specific answer if you can show us the code you have so far.

Comment: sure i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch fill a multi-dimensional array while fetching the SQL result or split into several SQL commands and therefore build up your array (1st fetching the names, than the products with values of every name).

I do not know which you prefer but as you have a large join splitting the SQL might not be the worst in terms of readability of your code. Performance impact may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Methinks this will do it

```
<?php

    $finalArray = array();
    $nameArray = array('Screens', 'Printers', 'Cash Drawers');

    foreach ($nameArray as $name) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            if ($row['name'] == $name) {

                if ($row['class_id'] == 1) {

                    $standard = array('id' => $row['system_step_product_id'], 'price' => $row['cost']);
                }
                else if ($row['class_id'] == 2) {

                    $business = array('id' => $row['system_step_product_id'], 'price' => $row['cost']);
                }
                else if ($row['class_id'] == 3) {

                    $premium = array('id' => $row['system_step_product_id'], 'price' => $row['cost']);
                }
            }
        }

        array_push($finalArray, array('name' => $name, 'standard_product' => $standard, 'business_product' => $business, 'premium_product' => $premium,));
    }

?>
```

Hopefully I got all the column names right.

This is what I tested it off of and I get the correct output http://codepad.org/yjU3gxbB

The only thing you may what to change is creating the name array dynamically

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        array_push($nameArray, $row['name']);
    }

    $nameArray = array_unique($nameArray);
```

However, PHP doesn't like it when you do a `mysql_fetch_assoc` twice on the same query.  You might want to do another query where you only select the `cd.name`